# Is there any way to filter C# DataView like this?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, dataview, bindingsource

I am writing some code for filtering data in `BindingSource` in c#.

In `DataTable`, I have one column and data is something like this,

> coding is very good

I want to filter data from string after every empty space like my example,

```
var ss = "coding is      ery"; 
var s = ss.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var filter = ColumnName + " like \'%" + s[0] + "%\' ";

        for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            filter = filter +  "AND " + ColumnName + " like \'%" + s[i] + "%\' ";
        }

BindingSource.Filter = filter;
```

The problem here is that I will get all the data (*coding is very good*). I don't want to get the data when word is not starting with the correct letter. Example,

> coding is ery.

I want to be like

> "coding very is" or "is very coding".

I want correct starting letters but position of word doesn't matter.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Comment: So you are asking to have a filter that check all full words but doesn't care about the position of all those words? So the "is coding  ery" should not work right?

Comment: You are right, "is coding ery" should not work. But not full words (only starting letters of word), also "is coding ve" should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it this way:

```
var filter = "(" + columnName
    + " like \'" + s[0] + "%\' "          // first word
    + " OR like \'% " + s[0] + "%\' )";   //in a sentence

for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    filter += "AND " + "(" + columnName
    + " like \'" + s[i] + "%\' "          // first word
    + " OR like \'% " + s[i] + "%\' )";   //in a sentence
}
```

Comment: This is working (with syntax correction) but for full words. I want to filter with correct starting letters of word: 's[i] %'. Example that i showed is working with string contain

Comment: I updated the code: 's[i]%' begin of your word at the begin of the sentence OR '% s[i]%' begin of your word anywhere in the sentence